# How to improve get object size with python and boto3?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I use Cloudian Storage on premise with S3 API. 
I need to monitor the used size of a bucket without Cloudian Admin Access.

With AWS CLI I use:

```sh
./aws --endpoint-url=https://s3-edc.emea.svc.corpintra.net:443 s3api list-objects --bucket edcs3mposdocifyb --output json --query "{\"size\": sum(Contents[].Size), \"objects\": length(Contents[])}"
```

This takes around 3 Minutes with following result:

```
{
    "size": 216317367311,
    "objects": 756771
}
```

I tried to get the same information with following python3 script using boto3.

```py
import boto3

total_bucket_size = 0
total_bucket_objects = 0
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id="****", aws_secret_access_key="***", endpoint_url="https://my.cloudian.fqdn:443", verify="MyChain.cer")
bucket = s3.Bucket("mybucketname")
bucket_name = bucket.name
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    obj_key = obj.key
    bucket_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, obj_key)
    obj_size = int(bucket_object.content_length)
    total_bucket_size += obj_size
    total_bucket_objects += 1
    print("%010d %s -> %d" %(total_bucket_objects,obj_key,obj_size))

print("Total size: %d" % total_bucket_size)
```

But this code will run some **hours**.

The goal is to write the result to an influxdb. It is quite easy with InfluxDBClient for python.

Any I idea why my boto3 code takes so long? 
What can I change to speed up the code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to reduce the time the python script uses to 4 minutes.

```py
total_bucket_size = 0
total_bucket_objects = 0
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id="13c81dba2e4e78628c76", aws_secret_access_key="zLmJVNVx03BQaUokmu6bSROskArFKROhwVyoOdcT", endpoint_url="https://s3-edc.emea.svc.corpintra.net:443", verify="DaimlerChain.cer")
bucket = s3.Bucket("edcs3mposdocifyb")
bucket_name = bucket.name
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    obj_key = obj.key
    #bucket_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, obj_key)
    #obj_size = int(bucket_object.content_length)
    obj_size = obj.size
    total_bucket_size += obj_size
    total_bucket_objects += 1
    print("%010d %s -> %d" %(total_bucket_objects,obj_key,obj_size))

print("Total size: %d" % total_bucket_size)
```